# JPanel with background image, with other panels overlayed

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jpanel

I want to have a JPanel which uses an image as a background, with this I want to add new panels to this panels so that they sit on top  of this background image. I have tried the following:

```
Image background;
 public Table(){
  super();
   ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("pokerTable.png"));
      background = ii.getImage();
      setSize(Constants.FRAME_WIDTH, Constants.TABLE_HEIGHT);
 }
 @Override
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
 {
  super.paintComponent(g); 
  if (background != null){
        g.drawImage(background, 0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),this);
  }

      JButton button = new JButton("hello world");

      JPanel OverlayedPanel1 = new JPanel();
      OverlayedPanel1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,50));
      OverlayedPanel1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600,50));
      OverlayedPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,50));
         OverlayedPanel1.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      OverlayedPanel1.setBackground(Color.yellow);

  }
```

The background image is displayed but the OverlayedPanel1 doesnt show. Any ideas?

Comment: Bad idea to create Swing objects in paint()! You should create them in the Table constructor or some method of your class.

Comment: Yes sorry I just put that there to demonstrate the example

Comment: you are not painting the panel, you are just creating it.
Which kind of object is Table? You should add the panel to the Table object (but not in the paint() method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't add `OverlayedPanel1` to the panel.

```
add(OverlayedPanel1);
```